# Facebook Page Insights PHP

Tags: php, facebook

My problem today is being caused by facebooks php sdk v5. I am trying to retrieve metrics from my specific page to use as analytics. I can currently retrieve the page information and other basic data so the code snippet I am having trouble with will be added below

Here is a snippet of my code :

```
   foreach($page as $key){
        if($key['name']=='PAGE NAME'){
            $pageId=$key['id'];
            try{
                $request = $fb->request('GET', '/' . $pageId. '/insights/page_impressions_organic',array('period' => 'month',),$access_token);
                $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);

            // ERROR Code
            }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                // When Graph returns an error
                echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                // When validation fails or other local issues
                echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
            $res=$response->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
            var_export($res);
            echo "</br>";
            // to print out page impressions
            foreach($res as $metric){
                 echo "Test".$metric->name;
            }

        }
}
```

My problem is I dont really understand the return of the request. The documentation for a beginner to facebook php is quite difficult to understand. I was wondering if somebody on here could explain how I would go about to getting the specific values from some metrics such as page_impressions_organic for example.

Here is part of the var_export result :

```
    array ( 0 => 
     array ( 'name' => 'page_impressions_organic', 'period' => 'day','values' =>  array (0 => 
       array ( 'value' => 0, 'end_time' => DateTime::__set_state(
         array( 'date' => '2016-03-25 07:00:00.000000', 'timezone_type' => 1, 'timezone' => '+00:00', )), )
```

From the above export i would like to pull the 'value' from this array. there are 2 more results after this being array(1=>...) and array(2=>...)

Comment: `var_dump($res)` shows you the structure of the data object. And after that, it just needs some basic knowledge of how to handle arrays and objects in PHP in general.

Comment: @CBroe I have added the result of a var_export($res) to my above code. If you could help could you tell me how to pull the 'value' from the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
array ( 0 => 
     array ( 'name' => 'page_impressions_organic', 'period' => 'day','values' =>  array (0 => 
       array ( 'value' => 0, 'end_time' => DateTime::__set_state(
         array( 'date' => '2016-03-25 07:00:00.000000', 'timezone_type' => 1, 'timezone' => '+00:00', )), )
```

You'll need to use:

```
echo $res[0]['values'][0]['value'];
```

to pull out the number associated with `value`.

Also, it's much easier to read your array if you format it with line breaks.  The array above is the same as

```
$res = array( 
        0 => array( 
            'name' => 'page_impressions_organic', 
            'period' => 'day',
            'values' => array(
                0 => array(
                    'value' => 0, 
                    'end_time' => DateTime::__set_state(array( 
                        'date' => '2016-03-25 07:00:00.000000', 
                        'timezone_type' => 1, 
                        'timezone' => '+00:00')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
);
```

Comment: your answer is perfect! it was just what I needed thank you kind sir!